# checkbox can't convert Symbol into String in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use the checkbox below on my ruby on rails app:

```
<%= check_box(:Monday,{:id => "Monday",:value => "Monday"}) %>
```

But it shows only checkbox not the text of the checkbox i.e "Monday" then I am using the below code for display the text with checkbox

```
<%= check_box :Monday, {:id => "Monday", :value => "Monday"}, "Monday" %>
```

But it gave me an error below:

```
can't convert Symbol into String
```

So what should I do to display the text with checkbox. Kindly me, waiting for reply, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using totally wrong way for taking inputs on the view.

Here is and example

```
<%=check_box_tag(monday, value = "monday", checked = false, options = {:id => "monday"}) %>
```

For more details read

[Rails Api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You are giving **Monday** as a symbol`(:Monday)`.

Try this:

```
<%= check_box_tag "Monday",id:=>"monday",:value =>"monday"%> Monday
```

OR

```
<%= check_box_tag 'Monday','Monday' %>  
   #=> <input id="Monday" name="Monday" type="checkbox" value="Monday" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails won't know what data to feed to the controller & db, So your checkbox needs to have a value associated with it

```
check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")
```

and  use

```
<%= f.check_box :monday, {:class => "your_class", :style => "your_style"}, "monday" %>
```

[Refer This Link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box)